# Launching an ImageJ plugin from NetBeans throws a JNI error. Launching it from ImageJ alone works fine

Tags: java, netbeans, java-native-interface, imagej

I have an ImageJ plugin and its sources which require a .dll library in order to operate. The plugin is working perfectly fine when I throw it int the ImageJ plugin folder, no problem.

But I have to modify the sources to add new features so I opened the project in NetBeans (it was already a NetBean project) and tried to start it from the IDE with a simple test class that start ImageJ and sets the plugin dir to the project dist\ dir. This works for all my other plugins but here I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError.

After some research and use of Dependency Walker I found out that I missed some .dll's in the project path. Now I have them all in the right places, executed with the -Djava.library.path="paths_to_all_my_libs" and I still get the error, Specific procedure not found.

It's really bothering me because I have to copy the .jar in dist to my ImageJ's installation, risking to mess things up and I can't use the console to output debugging stuff. Also I don't understand why I can't get it to work within NetBeans when everyting is fine with ImageJ alone.

Any idea is very welcome !

Answer (score 0):

You can go with two approaches here:

1. make sure to add your dll location to PATH
2. if you don't care about location (e.g. you are developing something for your own), use exact location of dll by using System.load - it takes explicit location of library as argument

Comment: That's my problem actually. I have all my dll in the path (wich is set up for my project with the -Djava.library.path option) but there is procedure, I assume this is a method in my native code, that can't be loaded when I use System.load or System.loadLibrary. I even tried taking the exact same path my working ImageJ uses but it doesn't work when executing from NetBeans

Comment: But do you set PATH environment variable as well? What is the error when you try to load library using System.load? Maybe there are some other dlls that are missing?

Comment: I checked the PATH variable and it does not contain the directory my .dll is in. I don't have the rights to modify it nor to copy the .dll somewhere in the PATH tho.
The error I get when using System.load is
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\path_to_my_dll\Pylon64JNI-visual.dll: Specified procedure could not be found
 at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)`
I made sure the libs Pylon64JNI-visual depends on (found with DW) are loaded beforehand by using System.loadLibrary for those that were in the path and System.load for the others.